# Filtering Django QuerySet based on ManyToMany relationship existence

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-q

## The Models

Here is the basic models setup we have.

A List has many Items, and an Item can be in many Lists. For a given Item, if *any* of its Lists are **good** (i.e., `list.bad == False`) then the Item is **good**. If an Item doesn't appear in any **good** Lists, then it is **bad**.

We have a custom QuerySet for Items, with a method for returning only good Items, and a method for returning only bad Items.

```python
class Item(models.Model):
    objects = ItemQuerySet.as_manager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class List(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    bad = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='lists')

class ItemQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def bad(self):
        return self.exclude(lists__bad=False)

    def good(self):
         return self.filter(lists__bad=False)
```

## The Scenario

Here's an example of a scenario we're having trouble with: one bad List, one good List, and two Items.

```
BadList:    GoodList:
- Item1     - Item1
- Item2
```

Since Item1 appears in at least one good list, it should come up in `Item.objects.good()`, and not in `Item.objects.bad()`.

Since Item2 does not appear in any good list, it should come up in `Item.objects.bad()`, and not in `Item.objects.good()`.

We can set up the scenario like so:

```python
# Create the two lists.
>>> goodlist = List.objects.create(name='goodlist', bad=False)
>>> badlist = List.objects.create(name='badlist', bad=True)

# Create the two items.
>>> item1 = Item.objects.create(name='item1')
>>> item2 = Item.objects.create(name='item2')

# Item1 goes in both lists
>>> goodlist.items.add(item1)
>>> badlist.items.add(item1)

# Item2 only in badlist
>>> badlist.items.add(item2)
```

And, indeed, `Item.objects.good()` and `Item.objects.bad()` work as we expect:

```python
>>> Item.objects.bad() # This returns what we want! Good!
<QuerySet [<Item: item2>]>

>>> Item.objects.good() # This returns what we want! Good!
<QuerySet [<Item: item1>]>
```

## The Problem

Thanks for bearing with me. Here's where our custom QuerySet goes wrong. If we access the `good()` and `bad()` custom QuerySet methods *through* a single List's Items, we get incorrect results.

```
>>> badlist.items.bad() # WRONG! We want to ONLY see item2 here!
<QuerySet [<Item: item1>, <Item: item2>]

>>> badlist.items.good() # WRONG! We want to see item1 here!
<QuerySet []>
```

It seems like, when we do `badlist.items.bad()`, the query *only* considers `badlist` in determining if the Items are bad, instead of considering all Lists that the Items are in. But I'm confused as to why that would be the case.

My thought is that, in the `ItemQuerySet.bad` method, I want something like `self.exclude(any__lists__bad=False)` instead of just `self.exclude(lists__bad=False)`. But of course that `any__` keyword doesn't actually exist, and I'm not sure how to express that logic correctly in a Django QuerySet. It seems that using `Q` objects might be the way forward, but I'm still not quite sure how to express a query like this with `Q` objects.

In our actual database, there are less than 100 Lists, but millions of Items. So, for performance reasons it's ideal to do this with one query, rather than a property or multiple queries.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you print out the query generated by `badlist.items.bad()` you'll see the issue: It will use a `WHERE` clause on the through table, thus limiting the lists to only badlist. You need to start from the `Item` level if you want to apply `bad` and `good` correctly, then filter by the items in the list.

```
item_ids = list(badlist.items.values_list('id'), flat=True)

Item.objects.bad().filter(id__in=item_ids)

Item.objects.good().filter(id__in=item_ids)
```

Edit: I can't test this without the schema, but I think you can use annotations to count up the number of lists and then filter via that

```
def annotate_good(self);
    return self.annotate(good=Count(Case(When(lists__bad=False, then=1), default=0)))

def good(self):
    return self.annotate_good().exclude(good=0)

def bad(self):
    return self.annotate_good().filter(good=0)
```

Otherwise, if performance really is an issue, I would add a good or bad field to the Item model and update it when saving so that the querying becomes dead simple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This does work properly, however I'm concerned that other people working with the code will attempt to use the `badlist.items.good()` route, not knowing any better. I want to avoid letting people get misled like that.

Additionally, I meant to mention this in the original post: In our actual database, there are less than 100 Lists, but millions of Items. So, for performance reasons it's ideal to do this with one query, rather than a property or multiple queries.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I think you can do this using queryset annotation. I edited my answer above with a solution I believe should work. Otherwise, to enhance performance, I'd just add the bad/good column to Item and update that, which makes the query much simpler